# ComboBox cannot scroll when dropdown is open if the PreviewMouseWheel event is handled

Tags: wpf, scroll, combobox

I have a ComboBox in xaml.

```xml
<ComboBox
 x:Name="comboBox"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Angle.Collection}"
 Text="{Binding Angle.Option, StringFormat='{}{0}°'}" />
```

**I do not want it to change item when cursor is over the combobox and rotate the mouse wheel.** So I handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` event like this:

```cs
comboBox.PreviewMouseWheel += (o,e)=>{e.Handled = true;};
```

But I run into the problem that when the dropdown is open, I cannot scroll the items if there are many items, even though I set `True` to the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: remove your PreviewMouseWheel  handler and fix original issue using some better method.

Comment: Please give me some tips about ```some better method```.

Comment: sure: make research, use google search, maybe investigate ComboBox source code, which MS made available

Comment: That is what I am doing. I am doing that in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `comboBox.PreviewMouseWheel += (o, e) => { if (!comboBox.IsDropDownOpen) e.Handled = true; };`